# How do I run two single page apps using the same s3 bucket and the same cloudfront distribution?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, single-page-application, amazon-cloudfront

https://example.com/subdirectory/* -> bucket/subdirectory/index.html
https://example.com/* -> bucket/index.html

And the wildcard (*) should apply only when the origin key is not present.

For eg if https://example.com/subdirectory/style/main.css is available then Cloudfront should use /subdirectory/style/main.css as key

I've setup the s3 bucket as static hosting and index.html as the index document

Comment: Couldn't you configure two different routes in your react app?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CloudFront Functions (JavaScript function that CloudFront executes for you at every edge location) to automatically rewrite URLs to index.html if they do not reference a specific file extension, or to the file referenced if there is a file extension. This link has an example function and details:
https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-cloudfront-functions/tree/main/url-rewrite-single-page-apps